Which value is picked up by a transaction stuck in mempool upon execution - one at Launch time or one at Execution time?
Could someone please confirm what happens in the following scenario:
    uint256 public reducer = 5;

    function calculateYield(uint256 lpTotal, address tokenA, address tokenB, uint256 minA, uint256 minB) public nonReentrant {
        uint256 lpBurnable = lpTotal - reducer; // <----- CHECKPOINT_1

        (uint256 claimedA, uint256 claimedB) = IRouter(router).removeLiquidity(
            tokenA, tokenB, lpBurnable, minA, minB, address(this), block.timestamp + 10 days  // <----- CHECKPOINT_2
        );

        reducer = 100;  
    }

    function updateReducer(uint256 val) public {
        reducer = val;  
    }  

Flow of events:

UserA calls calculateYield() when reducer equals it default value of 5.
It gets stuck in the mempool. Since the removeLiquidity() has a deadline of block.timestamp + 10 days, it remains there for some time.
Meanwhile UserB calls updateReducer(90) and thus sets reducer to 90.
After a day, the stuck transaction goes through successfully.

Question:

What is the value of reducer used by calculateYield() at CHECKPOINT_1? Is it 5 or is it 90? More accurately, since removeLiquidity() is pending, will it use lpBurnable as lpTotal - 5 or lpTotal - 90 at CHECKPOINT_2 when it finally executes?
If UserC now inspects the value of reducer, what would it be? Would it be 100 or would it be 90?

Also, is there a quick way to create a PoC around this so that such behaviour can be tested properly?
Thanks!

Transactions in the mempool are not executed and their effects are not in the blockchain. Only when a transaction gets included in a block, its effects take place and the blockchain's (and the contract's) state changes.
So if user A tries to change things, but his tx gets stuck in mempool and user B's tx goes through first, then A's tx sees the state as being after B's tx.
Whoever inspects the blockchain sees the current state (as per the executed transactions) - unless of course they're querying historical state.
You can probably simulate this behaviour the easiest in a local blockchain. I'm not sure how to do it, but you can start a local blockchain (with Foundry's Anvil or Hardhat) and somehow tell it to only execute certain transactions. But in reality you don't really need to simulate this kind of things - from the blockchain's perspective, the mempool is irrelevant and doesn't matter anything.

Thank you for your explanation! So I guess my point of confusion is this - calculateYield() attempted to call an external contract's (like uniswap's) IRouter(router).removeLiquidity() with lpBurnable as lpTotal - 5. This removal of liquidity remained pending for 8 days.  When it gets finally executed (before the deadline) i.e. is mined, the parameters are re-evaluated and hence removeLiquidity() gets called with lpBurnable as lpTotal - 90? Do I understand this right?

Quite. Parameters don't get "re-evaluated". Whenever a function is called (like removeLiquidity) it utilizes the latest blockchain & contract state for all calculations.

Answer1. I guess the reducer would be 90 cause at the time of execution of calculateYield() another transaction was processed which changed the value of reducer. This is almost equivalent to what happen in front-running
Answer2. Since the calculateYield() transaction is processed, the reducer would now be 100.
